# Dynamic where clause based on tkinter StringVar

Tags: sqlite, tkinter

Still having some trouble here:

I have attached 3 screenshots to illustrate the final tool and the bug I am currently trying to fix.

So what I want to achieve is that all comboboxes in this tool are filtered depending on the input of the combox(es) above prior to each of the comboboxes.

Now I tryed it for `Artikelbez_Liste` and `ArtikelNr_Liste`. The result is that if I choose a value for `Artikelbez_Liste` than `ArtikelNr_Liste` pops up as a new field and is filterd for the input of `Artikelbez_Liste`. So far so good, but I do not want the combobox to appear as a new box but that the existing one for `ArtikelNr_Liste` is filtered for the input of `Artikelbez_Liste` and updated if I change the value of `Artikelbez_Liste`.

Could somebody point out a way how to achieve this?

Pls find the code snipet for the relevant window below.`enter code here`

Thx in advance!

Cheers,
Jan

`class Eigenmaterial(Eigenreperatur):
def **init**(self, root):
self.root = root
self.root.geometry("600x600")
self.root.title("Erfassung Eigenmaterial")
self.Menüpunkt = tkinter.ttk.Label(self.root, text="Eigenmaterial", style='Eigen.TLabel')
self.Menüpunkt.pack(pady=10)
self.Kennzeichen_Liste()
self.Artikelbez_Liste()
self.ArtikelNr_Liste()
self.widgets_Eigenmaterial()
#self.Lagerort_Liste()

```
def Artikelbez_Liste(self):
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('//SERVER/Werkstatt/VR_Werkstatt.db')
    self.c = self.con.cursor()
    self.text_emc1 = tk.StringVar()
    self.ArtBez = self.c.execute("SELECT ArtBez FROM Eigenmaterial_Lagerbestand")
    self.emc1 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Artikelbezeichnung")
    self.emc1.pack()
    self.emc1 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.root, textvariable=self.text_emc1, width=17, state='readonly') #text="Artikelbezeichnung"
    self.emc1_cache = list()
    for ArtBez in self.ArtBez:
        self.emc1_cache.append(ArtBez)
    self.emc1["values"] = self.emc1_cache
    self.emc1.pack()
    #self.text_emc1.trace("w", self.ArtikelNr_Liste)
    self.text_emc1.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.ArtikelNr_Liste())
    self.c.close()
    self.con.close()

def ArtikelNr_Liste(self):
    ArtBez = self.text_emc1.get()
    #self.text_emc2 = tk.StringVar()
    self.con = sqlite3.connect('//SERVER/Werkstatt/VR_Werkstatt.db')
    self.c = self.con.cursor()
    self.ArtNr = self.c.execute("SELECT ArtNr FROM Eigenmaterial_Lagerbestand WHERE ArtBez = ?",(self.text_emc1.get(),))
    self.emc2 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Artikelnummer")
    self.emc2.pack()
    self.emc2 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.root,  text="Artikelnummer", width=17, state='readonly')#textvariable = self.text_emc2,
    self.emc2_cache = list()
    for ArtNr in self.ArtNr:
        self.emc2_cache.append(ArtNr)
    self.emc2["values"] = self.emc2_cache
    self.emc2.pack()
    #self.text_emc2.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.Lagerort_Liste())
    self.c.close()
    self.con.close()

def widgets_Eigenmaterial(self):
    self.l5 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Anzahl")
    self.l5.pack()
    self.db5 = tk.StringVar()
    self.e5 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.db5)
    self.e5.pack()
    self.l6 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Lagerort")
    self.l6.pack()
    self.db6 = tk.StringVar()
    self.e6 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.db6)
    self.e6.pack()

    # Definition des Submit-Buttons (Erfasste Daten in DB schreiben)
    self.button_submit = tkinter.ttk.Button(self.root, text="Daten Speichern",  style='Speichern.TButton',
                                   command=lambda: self.submit_Eigenmaterialverbrauch_to_db())
    self.button_submit.pack(padx=15, pady=15)`
```

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1iub.png)
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4e8c.png)

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted? Is it not acting the way  you expect? What is it doing, and how is it different from what you expect? Also, the indentation if the first line of code is broken.

Comment: Yea my bad! Well it is not filtering anything at all in the 2nd combobox. So I do get both comboboxes, but I get all values present in the db even if I select a value in the 1st combobox...

Comment: Should `self.emc2["values"] = self.emc1_cache` be `self.emc2["values"] = self.emc2_cache` instead?

Comment: @CoolCloud: no, if the code is using using `lambda` then it must be `self.Artike1Nr_Liste()`.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `ArtikelNr_Liste` is being called after `Artikelbez_Liste`, and after the user has made a selection?  Have you verified that `ArtBez` is what you're assuming it is? Have you verified that `self.ArtNr` is returning what you think it should be returning?

Comment: HY thanks for the feedback! I changed the part self.emc2["values"] = self.emc2_cache as suggested. I did not notice the mistake as I am working with a TEST db where Number and Name are the same. So now I don't get any results for the ArtNr at all...

Comment: @BryanOakley how can I ensure that ArtikelNr_Liste is being called after Artikelbez_Liste, and after the user has made a selection? How can I achive this?

Comment: Remove `text="Artikelbezeichnung"` from the line `self.emc1 = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(self.root, textvariable=self.text_emc1, text="Artikelbezeichnung", width=17, state='readonly')`.

Comment: @acw1668 thx it helped! Now if I choose a value for Artikelbez_Liste the 2nd combobox appears and all values here are filterd accordingly. But if I change the value in the first box the 2nd combobox is duplicated and this goes on and on... Can u point out a way to avoid this? Also i would like to see all comboboxes together indepent from the fact whether a value is selected or not.